# Add harmonic to a signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

How can I add a harmonic of the input signal ?

- without  making frequency estimations ( frequency is provided )
- by making frequency estimations

input  : vectorized form of signal
output : same format as input

NOTE : If you know answer, can you give me algorithm or link which will help me to solve this problem.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fft.html

Comment: That's not a question about programmation. More like theory of the signal.

Comment: Candidate moving to for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the frequency is known, then you can presumably add a harmonic just by adding a sine wave of the appropriate frequency (i.e. double the known frequency) to the signal. Something like:

```
result = signal .* sin((0:(1/sample_rate):length_of_signal) * freq));
```

When the frequency is unknown you could use an FFT (@L7ColWinters linked to the docs for that) to find the frequencies. Since you can convert a signal from the frequency domain back to the time domain ([ifft](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/ifft.html) for the inverse), it might be easier to do the FFT, add the harmonic and then do an inverse FFT, or once you know the frequency from the FFT you could add the sine wave to the original input as in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

- Suppose your input is the time domain signal with amplitude array `A` with interval `[0, t0]`. Then loop over `i` with

  A[i] = A[i] + A0 * sin (2 pi f dt)

where dt is the time difference between each array element, i.e. `dt = N/t0`.

- If you do the Fourier transform first, you just need to add the `A0` at the location corresponding to frequency `f`, and then do inverse Fourier transform, following link by @L7ColWinters

Answer (score 1):

If you look through the [trig identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-.2C_triple-.2C_and_half-angle_formulae), you will see that

cos(2x) = 2 * (cos(x))^2 -1

Since the first harmonic is double the fundamental frequency, you can simply square your input, scale as needed and remove DC offset.  Frequency doen't need to be known or estimated.

Keep in mind that Nyquist still applies, so you may have to low-pass your input to prevent aliasing.